# How to seed a database only when there is no documents in the database using mongoose

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose, seeding

I have a seeder function that will seed data into a database. I also have the seeder run when the app starts.  Now I am seeding repeated data. How do I modify my function so that it only seeds the database with data if there are no data in the database collection?

```js
const importData = async () => {
    try {
        await ExhibitModel.create(exhibits);
        console.log("Data imported");
        process.exit();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you make database seeding a part of your deployment pipeline rather than including it in your application?

Comment: Perhaps, you can query the collection if any documents exist (using a method like findOne), before.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use insert.

Use [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) with `upsert=true`. Update will look for the document that matches your query, then it will modify the fields you want and then, you can tell it `upsert: true` if you want to insert if no document matches your query.

```
db.collection.update(filter, update, {upsert:true})
```